# Bitbucket call webhook php code not executing git command and when I execute from command prompt same command runs perfectly

Tags: php, bitbucket, bitbucket-webhook

When I commit my code form source tree bitbucket triggers a webhook that hit php code

```
exec('cd /d ' . $web_root_dir . ' && '. $git_bin_path  . ' pull origin master');
```

it won't execute but when I copy the same command by copying from the log on command prompt it execute perfectly.

I've tried my heart out on this but no result.

Comment: Git doesn't execute bitbucket-webhooks; only bitbucket does that. I snipped the [tag:git] tag, but I suspect this isn't a php issue either, just a bitbucket one...

Comment: @torek No, webhook triggers the path that is provided to push webhook but once that triggers the file then these mentioned commands doesn't execute and same command when I copy form log that is created against that file is working absolutely fine.

Comment: I am not sure what a "form log" might be (is this a typo, "copy *from* log"?) but running a command locally, on your computer, is very different from having Bitbucket run a command on *their* computer, because they have to be careful that you don't run *arbitrary* commands that could alter someone else's repository, for instance. I'd also note that `cd /d/foo` is probably the *wrong path* on bitbucket as the repository is probably not under a `/d` top level directory. **All of these are bitbucket-related issues.**

Comment: @torek I've changed the command a bit 
**cd /d d:\directorytogit && git pull origin master**
But still it's not giving me the  response when webhook call this link and the same command that hook is calling I'm making the log and I copy the command from the log and run in CMD and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: Given that Bitbucket hosts are likely running Linux, `d:` is never going to be right. It looks like they expand a text literal `BITBUCKET_HOME`, based on [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-create-a-simple-hook-in-bitbucket-server-779171711.html).

Comment: @torek I've ticked a bit in this instead of calling webhook. I created Task scheduler to run git commands and it's working perfectly :)